# Is there a way to schedule a deletion of a file on Firebase Storage?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'am trying to build a ReactJS app which allows users to upload and download some files. I already have Firebase storage upload and download functionality in my app. The thing is that I want to schedule a task which will delete a file in 10 minutes for example each time user uploads his file.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is built into Firebase for this, but Cloud Storage (the underlying storage mechanism) has something known as [object lifecycle management](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle), with which:

> you can assign a lifecycle management configuration to a bucket. The configuration contains a set of rules which apply to current and future objects in the bucket. When an object meets the criteria of one of the rules, Cloud Storage automatically performs a specified action on the object.

If the deletion rules are really as constant as you say, that's where I'd look.

If the rules are more complex, I'd typically start with Cloud Functions as there I can write [code that run periodically](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) to do the cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a reliable server-side solution for this, you can make use of a [Scheduled Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions).

Here is an implementation of a Node-based Cloud Function:

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

admin.initializeApp();

/**
 * Scheduled Cloud Function that deletes files older than 10 minutes,
 * checking every 5 minutes.
 *
 * Files must be prefixed with "tmpUserUploads" to be checked by this
 * function. If a file has a temporary or event-based hold on it, it
 * will be skipped over by this function.
 *
 * @author samthecodingman [MIT License]
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67724030/3068190
 *
 * @example
 * "tmpUserUploads/someFile.png" // -> checked
 * "tmpUserUploads/users/someUserId/someFile.png" // -> checked
 * "profilePictures/someUserId/profile@1x.png" // -> not checked
 */
export cleanupTemporaryFiles =
functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun(async (context) => {
  // variables for tracking statistics
  let processedCount = 0, disposedCount = 0, skippedCount = 0, erroredCount = 0, totalCount = 0;
  const errorCountsByCode = {};
  
  try {
    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();

    // Query for all files starting with "tmpUserUploads"
    const [filesArray] = await bucket.getFiles({
      prefix: "tmpUserUploads"
    });
    
    totalCount = filesArray.length;

    // variables with our settings to be reused below
    const TIMESTAMP_TEN_MINUTES_AGO = Date.now() - 600000;
    const DELETE_OPTIONS = { ignoreNotFound: true };

    // If this number is regularly large, consider shortening the interval above
    console.log("Found ${totalCount} files that need to be checked.");

    // Process purge of each file as applicable keeping track of the results
    const deleteOldFileResults = await Promise.all(
      filesArray.map(async (file) => {
        let metadata;
        try {
          // get the metadata for this file object
          [metadata] = await file.getMetadata();

          // pull out the bits we need
          const { temporaryHold, eventBasedHold, timeCreated } = metadata;

          // held files should not be deleted (will throw an error if you try)
          const activeHold = temporaryHold || eventBasedHold;

          // dispose when not held and older than 10 minutes
          const dispose = !activeHold && timeCreated < TIMESTAMP_TEN_MINUTES_AGO;

          if (dispose) {
            await file.delete(DELETE_OPTIONS);
            disposedCount++;
          } else if (activeHold) {
            skippedCount++;
          }
          
          processedCount++;

          return { file, metadata, disposed: dispose, skipped: activeHold };
        } catch (error) {
          // trap the error so other files still attempt to be deleted

          erroredCount++;
          processedCount++;

          const code = deleteResult.error.code || "unknown";
          const errorCountForCode = (errorsByCode[code] || 0) + 1;

          // Consider crashing function if same error code is encountered many times
          // if (errorCountForCode > 10) {
          //   throw new Error(`Error code "${code}" has been encountered more than 10 times`);
          // }

          errorCountsByCode[code] = errorCountForCode;

          return { file, metadata, disposed: false, skipped: true, error };
        }
      })
    );

    // Assemble an informative log message

    const skippedLogMessage = skippedCount === 0
      ? "No files had active holds"
      : `${skippedCount} of these were skipped due to active holds`;
    const errorLogMessage = erroredCount === 0
      ? "no errors were encountered"
      : `${erroredCount} were skipped due to errors (Error code breakdown: ${JSON.stringify(errorCountsByCode)})`;

    console.log(`${disposedCount}/${totalCount} temporary files were purged. ${skippedLogMessage} and ${errorLogMessage}.`);
  } catch (error) {
    const stats = JSON.stringify({
      disposed: disposedCount,
      skipped: skippedCount,
      errored: erroredCount,
      errorCodeCounts: errorCountsByCode
    });
    
    console.error(`Critical failure: ${error.message}. Encounted after processing ${processedCount}/${totalCount} files: ${stats}`);
  }
})
```